# Multi-Array of XML Requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, xmlhttprequest

OMG, I am in need of a way to set up arrays of XML Requests based on the idShout - 1.

So it would be something like this...

```
var req = new Array();
req[idShout - 1] = ALL XML Data...
```

Here's what I got so far but it's not working at all :(

```
var idShout;
var req = new Array();

function htmlRequest(url, params, method)
{
    req[req.push] = ajax_function();
    for (i=0;i<req.length;i++)
    {
        (function (i) {
            if (req[i])
            {
                if (method == "GET")
                {
                    req[i].onreadystatechange = function()
                    {
                        if (req[i].readyState != 4)
                            return;
                        if (req[i].responseText !== null && req[i].status == 200)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("shoutbox_area" + idShout).innerHTML = req[i].responseText;
                        }
                    }
                }
                req[i].open(method,url,true);
                if (method == "POST")
                    req[i].setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                if (params == "")
                    req[i].send(null);
                else
                    req[i].send(params);

                return req[i];
            }
            else
                return null;
        })(i);
    } 
}



function ajax_function()
{
    var ajax_request = null;

    try
    {
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajax_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    catch (e)
    {
        // IE Browsers
        try
        {
            ajax_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            try
            {
                ajax_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                //No browser support, rare case
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    return ajax_request;
}

function send(which)
{
    var send_data = "shoutmessage=" + document.getElementById("shout_message" + which).value;
    var url = smf_prepareScriptUrl(smf_scripturl) + "action=dreamaction;sa=shoutbox;xml;send_shout="+ which;

    htmlRequest(url, send_data, "POST");

    document.getElementById("shout_message" + which).value = "";
    document.getElementById("shout_message" + which).focus();
    return true;
}

function startShouts(refreshRate, shoutCount)
{
    clearInterval(Timer[shoutCount-1]);
    idShout = shoutCount;
    show_shouts();
    Timer[shoutCount - 1] = setInterval("show_shouts()", refreshRate);

    return;
}

function show_shouts()
{
    var url = smf_prepareScriptUrl(smf_scripturl) + "action=dreamaction;sa=shoutbox;xml;get_shouts=" + idShout;
    htmlRequest(url, "", "GET");
}
```

Any help at all on this would be greatly appreciated...
Basically, I'm setting the Timer Arrays in a different function before this, and I call startShouts which is supposed to show all of the information, but startShouts gets called more than once, which is why I have idShout set to equal shoutCount.  So it will go something like this:  shoutCount = 1, shoutCount = 2, shoutCount = 3, everytime it is being called.  So I set the req[idShout - 1] array and it should return the result right??

Well, I get no errors in Firefox in the error console with this code above, but it doesn't work... Any ideas anyone??  As it needs to output into more than 1 area... argg.

Thanks for any help you can offer here :)

Thanks guys :)

Also, a little more info on this...
Basically there is 1 or more Shoutboxes on any given page (Don't ask why?), I need to be able to grab the info of this and put it into the document.getElementById("shoutbox_area" + idShout), since the idShout for each element changes incrementing by 1 for each Shoutbox that is on that page.  The values for the Shoutbox can be different, example the refreshRate can be different.  1 Shoutbox can have a refresh rate of like 2000 milliseconds, while the other can have a rate of 250 milliseconds, they need to be different and refresh at the times that are defined for them, so this is why I decided to make a Timer array, though not sure I have setup the Timer array the way it is meant to be setup for the setInterval function.  Here is the way it get's done in a different javascript function that runs just before startShouts gets called...

This part is outside of the function and within the document itself:

```
var Timer = new Array();
```

And this part is in the function...

```
Timer[shoutCount - 1] = "";
```

So not sure if this is correctly setup for Timers...?

Answer (score 0):

Since XHRs are asynchronous, by the time the `readystatechange` callback function fires the value of `i` has changed.  You need to create a separate closure for the `i` variable during your loop.  The easiest way to do this is wrap an anonymous function around the code block and call it with `i` passed as the first argument:

```
for (i=0;i<req.length;i++)
{
    (function (i) {
        if (req[i])
        {
            if (HttpMethod == "GET")
            {
                req[i].onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if (req[i].readyState != 4)
                        return;
                    if (req[i].responseText !== null && req[i].status == 200)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("shoutbox_area" + idShout).innerHTML = req[i].responseText;
                    }
                }
            }
            req[i].open(HttpMethod,url,true);
            if (HttpMethod == "POST")
                req[i].setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            if (params == "")
                req[i].send(null);
            else
                req[i].send(params);

            return req[i];
        }
        else
            return null;
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have made the following change, and inputted it above in the QUESTION, but nothing has changed and still nothing in the elements...??  Still no errors, but there's nothing in any of the elements...??

Comment: Also, I am using method instead of HTTPMethod now, but it shouldn't make any difference anyhow...

Comment: Ok, I changed this `req[req.push] = ajax_function();` to this `req[idShout - 1] = ajax_function();` and now it is working for the last shoutbox, but it doesn't show any of the info for the one's before it??  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you think it's causing a problem because I am calling it on page load??  Any way to work-around this??